# Problem with opening Blender

Tags: error

When I open blender it opens up and shows a grey screen for a few seconds then closes. How do I fix this?

I still haven't managed to use Blender on my PC.
I have an HP Pavilion G6 laptop.
With Windows 10 Enterprise
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz   2.10 GHz
Installed RAM:  8.00 GB
Graphic card: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000

Comment: I suspect a misinstallation. Tried re-downloading the installer and starting again.

Comment: Your cpu is under the minimun requirements, try with an older Blender version [HERE](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) like 2.79

Answer (score 1):

The i3-2310M is just over 10 years old and probably doesn't meet the compute requirements for current versions.